# Print double with two decimal problem in java

Tags: java, loops

I have problem with similar task.

Here is the task:

[image]

[The sample tests are:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NaAZ.png)

This is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MinMaxSumAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double average;
        double sum = 0;
        double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double numbers = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; ++i) {
           int num = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num > max) max = num;
            if (num < min) min = num;
            sum += num;
        }
        average = sum / numbers;
        System.out.println("min=" + (df.format(min)));
        System.out.println("max=" + (df.format(max)));
        System.out.println("sum=" + (df.format(sum)));
        System.out.println("avg=" + (df.format(average)));
    }
}
```

[It work correct, but in "judge system" who test my code have some errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAjNZ.png)

Can you help me to find what's wrong with my code?

**Edit:**
I change sum, max & min from double to int, and test result have minimal changes:

Test 2:

[image]

Comment: Your code is failing to accept decimal inputs.

Comment: It is better to change nextInt to nextLine and then parse each line.

Comment: Thank's you very much, it's working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is failing to accept decimal inputs that's why you are receiving `InputMismatchException`. Change this line

```
int num = scanner.nextInt();
```

to

```
double num = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I'm so blind... :) 

Change all int's to double, but still have the same problem

https://imgur.com/4e0b5b0b-19fe-4bba-9fed-d6f410f9357f